# Book recommendation: fractals

Tags: book-recommendation, fractals

I’m looking for a book to learn a bit more about fractals. I have to say I am a theoretical physicist, not a mathematician so it’d rather be mathematically simple (I don’t know what kind of maths are used for fractals though). I don’t want something applied to physics either. Any recommendations? Is Mandelbrot’s “The fractal geometry of nature” a good book?

Comment: Such recommendations are out of the scope of this site.

Comment: Maybe [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=fractals+for+physicists) will be helpful, but without knowing anything about your math background and goals, I think any suggestions you get will likely be as suitable for you as simply randomly picking suggested books at amazon.